# Transactions with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have table with InnoDB storage engine. 
I want start insert proccess when all is correctly. 
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily with the **MySQLi** class which supports transactions.

***Here is an example:***

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
    $mysqli->autocommit(false);

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1)");
    $mysqli->rollback();

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (2)");
    $mysqli->commit();
?>
```

[Here you can find some documentation an examples.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php#example-1593)

Also If you are using a framework, check it's documentation. The usually have a really cool implementations and approaches to transactions.

Here is an example of very smart transactions algorithms in CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

CodeIgniter handles transactions automatically and roles back the changes if there is an error in one of the queries.
[CodeIgniter's Approach to Transactions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html)

Comment: Can you cite examples for your second paragraph? From what I've seen, transaction support in PHP frameworks tends to be bare-bones if it exists at all.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt How is that?

Comment: your example is the minimum I'd expect. I wouldn't call it "smart" unless it does stuff like nested and declarative transactions.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Check the link with the documentation. There is also a manual mode for running transactions. I posted a very simple example because it wasn't related much wit the question.

Comment: I've read the link. As I'd say: the minimum I'd expect from any framework that provides DB abstractions.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of which PHP library you're using, you can always initiate a transaction using either of these statements:

- `SET autocommit = off`
- `BEGIN`
- `START TRANSACTION`

Once started you can do a bunch of work, and when you're ready to save it permanently, do a commit:

- `COMMIT`

Or, when you want to undo the work in progress (up to the previous commit moment) issue a rollback:

- `ROLLBACK`

You can simply run these as ordinary SQL statements with any php library for mysql.